# The IT industry is developing now and will be developing in the future? Is that correct?

Tags: passive-voice

I have had some argument with my teacher about this phrase. He said that it isn't correct to construct to say in that way:

> The IT industry is developing now and will be developing in the future?

And said that correct form of this sentence would be something like that

> The IT industry is developing now and will be being developed in the future?

But why? Can you explain me why it has to be that way?

I guest it because The IT Industry cannot develop itself, somebody has to do it. And in this case he have to use passive voice (an force is being applied to the industry)

But why is it possible to say in active voice?

> The IT industry is developing

Or can you explain how to properly construct this sentence (or something similar, where object by itself can't do anything and somebody else has to do something towards this object to change its state).

Comment: A more apt way of phrasing this would be "...and will continue to develop..."

Comment: At the very least, there should be some consistency.  Either both verbs should be in the active voice - "The IT industry **is developing** now and **will be developing** in the future," - or both verbs should be in the passive voice - "The IT industry **is being developed** now and **will be being developed** in the future."